# Simple way to calculate minimum distance beween two 3D objects

Tags: python, algorithm, math

Suppose I have two tetrahedras and it's vertex coordinates. They cannot have parts inside each other and their distance will always be greater than 0. How to calculate the minimum distance between them?

My approach, which I did not like very much, because I'm having problems representing the line equations in code:

- For each tetrahedra, calculate 6 lines equations, one for each edge.
- Them calculate the distance between the points of tetrahedra A to the lines equations of tetrahedra B. Store those 24 (6 edges, 4 vertexes) distance in a list.
- Do the same in the other way.
- Find the minimum between the 48 distances calculated

Is there any algorithm to find minimum distance between 3D objects, given it's coordinates? I believe the above procedure solve the problem but it is very tedious to write all the equations

Comment: The min distance doesn't have to involve a tip of either tetrahedra.

Comment: @Dave I didn't understand your point

Comment: I suggest you start with a simpler exercise: the distance from a line segment to another line segment. Then a line segment to a triangle. Then a triangle to another triangle. After that, two tetrahedra will be straightforward.

Comment: @EgydioPacheco You're checking the dist between the tips of A to the lines of B & vice versa. This won't always contain the min dist.

Comment: Consider two tetrahedra almost touching with two of their faces, oriented like this: https://i.imgur.com/PkSlKDn.png. The distance between the vertices is significant whilst the objects are in reality very close.

Comment: Check out the Gilbert-Johnson-Keerthi (GJK) algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Keerthi_distance_algorithm

Comment: In your solution, there is no need to store the distances, and how can it be tedious to find the equations if a computer does it for you ? By the way, your solution is wrong, as the shorted distance is not necessarily vertex-to-edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my simple approach.
If we have tetrahedra points in  arrays t1 and t2, we initiate minimal distance to distance between any two vertices in tetrahedron A and tetrahedron B. We loop over all faces in A and B and, and define functions face_p_1(alpha,beta) which we use to get any point on that face by scanning parameters alpha and beta in range [0,1].
And finally we minimize distance (using scipy) between all points in each pair of faces in A and B.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection, Line3DCollection
import numpy as np
import itertools
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def mindist (t1,t2):
    dmin=np.linalg.norm(t1[0]-t2[0])
    p0=t1[0]
    p1=t2[0]

    for face_t1 in itertools.combinations([0,1, 2, 3], 3):
        for face_t2 in itertools.combinations([0,1, 2, 3], 3):
            pts_f_t1=t1[list(face_t1)]
            pts_f_t2=t2[list(face_t2)]

            def face_p_1(alpha1,beta1):
                v1=pts_f_t1[1]-pts_f_t1[0]
                v2=pts_f_t1[2]-pts_f_t1[1]
                return(pts_f_t1[0]+(v1*alpha1+v2*alpha1*beta1))

            def face_p_2(alpha2,beta2):
                v1=pts_f_t2[1]-pts_f_t2[0]
                v2=pts_f_t2[2]-pts_f_t2[1]
                return(pts_f_t2[0]+(v1*alpha2+v2*alpha2*beta2))

            def fpdist(a):
                alpha1,beta1,alpha2,beta2=a
                return(np.linalg.norm(face_p_1(alpha1,beta1)-face_p_2(alpha2,beta2)))

            res=minimize(fpdist,[0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5],bounds=[(0,1),(0,1),(0,1),(0,1)])
            if( res["fun"] < dmin):
                dmin=res["fun"]
                p0=face_p_1(*(res["x"][[0,1]]))
                p1=face_p_2(*(res["x"][[2,3]]))
    return dmin,p0,p1

    
def plot_tetrahedron(v,ax):
    ax.scatter3D(v[:, 0], v[:, 1], v[:, 2])
    verts = [ [v[0],v[1],v[2]], [v[0],v[1],v[3]], [v[0],v[2],v[3]] , [v[1],v[2],v[3]]  ]
    ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(verts, 
     facecolors='cyan', linewidths=1, edgecolors='r', alpha=.25))
```

Here are some tests with plots

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

t1=np.array([[ 0.5,  0.5, -0.2],[ 0.6, -0.1, -0.2],[-0.2,  0.6, -0.1],[ 0. ,  0. ,  0.6]])
t2=np.array([[0.6 , 0.65, 0.55],[1.4 , 0.75, 0.55],[0.6 , 1.45, 0.65],[0.8 , 0.85, 1.35]])

dmin,p1,p2=mindist (t1,t2)

plot_tetrahedron(t1,ax)
plot_tetrahedron(t2,ax)

ax.plot(*(array([ p1 , p2 ]).T), c='k')
```

[image]

another case

```
t1=np.array([[-0.15 , -0.225, -0.075],[-0.05 , -0.825, -0.775],[-0.85 , -0.125, -0.675],[-0.65 , -0.725,  0.025]])
t2=np.array([[0.6 , 0.65, 0.55],[1.4 , 0.75, 0.55],[0.6 , 1.45, 0.65],[0.8 , 0.85, 1.35]])


t1=np.array([[-0.15 , -0.225, -0.075],[-0.05 , -0.825, -0.775],[-0.85 , -0.125, -0.675],[-0.65 , -0.725,  0.025]])
t2=np.array([[0.6 , 0.65, 0.55],[1.4 , 0.75, 0.55],[0.6 , 1.45, 0.65],[0.8 , 0.85, 1.35]])
```

[image]

```
t1=np.array([[0.1, 0.1, 0.1],[0.9, 0.2, 0.1],[0.1, 0.9, 0.2],[0.3, 0.3, 0.9]])
t2=np.array([[0.6 , 0.65, 0.55],[1.4 , 0.75, 0.55],[0.6 , 1.45, 0.65],[0.8 , 0.85, 1.35]])
```

[image]

and case with two parallel  faces

```
t1=np.array([[-1 , 0, 0],[1 , 0, 0],[0 , sqrt(2), 0],[0 , sqrt(2)/3, sqrt(2)]])
t2=np.array([[-1 , 0, -1],[1 , 0, -1],[0 , sqrt(2), -1],[0 , sqrt(2)/3, -sqrt(2)-1]])
```

[image]

Comment: Nice plots, though you left out the plotting in the code.

Comment: Plots functions are now added

Comment: The minimum distance can be between a vertex and either another vertex or an edge or a face, or between two edges. I don't see that clearly appear in your code nor in the discussion, and I question its correctness. Isn't a minimizer algorithm overkill when there are simple analytical solutions ?

Comment: First figure shows vertex to line min distance, the third figure shows vertex to face min distance. Yes, this is an overkill, as the simple solution was requested. Analytical solutions should be more efficient but the code is less elegant. If you have an example of when the code fails, please let me know.